# Different ERC20-Tokens (incl. ETH) on a single address. Is it OK?

Tags: addresses

Where exactly ERC20 contract says that it allows users to manage a variety of different ERC20-Tokens (incl. ETH) on a single address?

Thanks in advance!

——
Sorry that my question is not clear.

A CEX propose me the same deposit address for ETH and a few other tokens. So I can transfer 2 different tokens to that address. How it works?

What blockchain explorer show to me If I try to view that address after that? Will balance show me 2 tokens?

Comment: Not sure what your question means. An ERC20 contract isnt aware of any other contract by default, it just exists by itself, undependantly of ETH or other ERC20 contracts

Comment: Sorry that my question is not clear. 


A CEX propose me the same deposit address for ETH and a few other tokens. So I can transfer 2 different tokens to that address. How it works? 

What show blockchain explorer to me If I try to view that address after that? Will balance show me 2 tokens?

Comment: Most likely, yes. Unless the CEX automatically transfer them to another address where they store more assets (which is probably the case)

Answer (score 0):

ERC20 is a standard for implementing tokens on the Ethereum blockchain. The standard specifies a set of functions and events that a token contract must implement in order to be considered an ERC20 token. The ERC20 standard does not specify anything about managing multiple tokens on a single address.

That being said, some wallet applications and exchanges may allow users to manage multiple ERC20 tokens on a single address by using a single Ethereum address to track the balances of multiple ERC20 tokens. This is not a requirement of the ERC20 standard, but rather a feature that some applications and exchanges choose to implement.

If you want to manage multiple ERC20 tokens on a single address, you will need to find a wallet or exchange that supports this feature. You can then add the ERC20 tokens you want to manage to your wallet or exchange account, and they will be tracked on a single Ethereum address.